# Is there an expression like "to use [something] in full"?

Tags: expressions

Here is the context:

> I got Schengen visa to attend a meetup in Berlin this Saturday. It's a multi-entrance visa that expires April 24th. Figured I have *to use it in full*. What IT conferences in Europe would you advise to visit in the nearest future?

I.e. the meaning is that I'm going to use the visa as much as possible. Does it sound OK? Or there is no such expression? How would you say the same?

Answer (score 4):

I think that 'to use it in full' is not wrong but does strike me, a native speaker of British English, as sounding a bit odd. You could say "I figured I should make the most of it".

Your final sentence is definitely wrong, however. It would be better to say '... advise me to visit..."